# Typescript: property of derived class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, properties

i am sorry for that question but i couldn't find the right setting for typescript or the correct definition for the inheritance.

```js
abstract class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cow extends Animal {}

class Test {
    dog!: Dog;

    constructor() {
        this.dog = new Cow();
    }
}
```

What i tried was defining properties on the derived classes so typescript errors because of different properties but that's not what i want.
I want that typescript causes an error on this type of initialization.

Why doesn't it generate an error or what config can i set in tsconfig to do so?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing an error is that TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on the shape of things), not *nominal* (based on the names/identities of things), and there's nothing structural that distinguishes instances of `Dog` from instances of `Cow.` This can be surprising if (like me) you're used to nominal type systems such as those in Java or C#.

If there were (a property that `Dog` instances have that `Cow` instances don't, in this case), you'd get an error:

```typescript
abstract class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {
    bark() {}
}
class Cow extends Animal {
    moo() {}
}

class Test {
    dog: Dog;

    constructor() {
        this.dog = new Cow(); // <== Error: Property 'bark' is missing in type 'Cow' but required in type 'Dog'.
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAXwCgKU0MARAewHMEBTADwlewBMMcCRUhQSiEIYFADWACgCUpSpRroEAYQYB3Np258seQsRIix+Bg3mKKlaqlUAVVpGFiEPZgC4EjJgG4qN1gGbEgoAFd4BigrEzc3CAALXDAAOg8WAF4EbFZtDU15PwQAehKEAB5M7IBRKCho7wAFBoAHVigIAE8EAHIJaV6EFIR8FLBcbBZJhG72voKhkHDEKFYAR3DcNZ5h7Fmu+d7fXtTTUSUgA)

*(Side note: No need for the definitely-assigned annotation [`!`] on the `dog` property if you assign to it in the constructor.)*

> What i tried was defining properties on the derived classes so typescript errors because of different properties but that's not what i want. I want that typescript causes an error on this type of initialization.

In general, types that don't have any properties or methods are problematic in TypeScript, since you can assign basically anything to them. The usual solution if you really don't have anything instance-specific that's meaningful is to use a *branding* property, like this:

```typescript
abstract class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {
    readonly __type__ = "Dog";
}

class Cow extends Animal {
    readonly __type__ = "Cow";
}

class Test {
    dog: Dog;

    constructor() {
        this.dog = new Cow(); // <== Error: Type 'Cow' is not assignable to type 'Dog'.
                              //       Types of property '__type__' are incompatible.
                              //         Type '"Cow"' is not assignable to type '"Dog"'.
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAXwCgKU0MARAewHMEBTADwlewBMMcCRUhQSiEUVsB4NsyAJ4IA+oohyADq2UIAvAgBEjJnoDcFStVToEAYQYB3Np258seQsRIixEqTPlKVdU1FHX1bOxMzKhorABVWSGExBGkmAC4EQ1MvUVgZSCgAV3gGKAAKAEok5LEIAAtcMAA6VNDsVgdwyuMEAHpehAAebV0AUSgoUozYoIQAcnC5hEaEbAZEWlwmbFBkVgQIBgPZucM5ppyaq+ubvoGrmY0MBgAzBDVJjShVeeVVDWUS2AEmW2Dy+DUwAguBAewutwRiP6t0e+zmenCeiWKzWG3QWx2sP2h2OGnmBmYWPhYkoZCAA)

I realize you didn't want instance properties on them, but because of the structural nature of the type system, you need them to distinguish the types.